# jpg file shows in chrome but not in safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I downloaded a jpg file from my ip cam.

but the file seems broken or something about its format.

I couldn't open it using safari or preview.app(macOS),

but it shows in chrome.

What I really trying to do is download it programmatically and show in UIImageView, but the image data is always nil.

---

I don't know much about image format and the question is strange,

so if you're willing to help me and see whats going on with that picture,

the image: [broken jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeQ6p.jpg)

and thanks for your time!

---

**UPDATE 2017/03/30 :**

Still haven't found the answer for how to decode motion jpeg frame.

From what I googled, the difference is DHT, but don't know how to add it to a frame.

As far as I know, there are few third-party libs like libjpeg-turbo, ffmpeg but haven't found an example.

If you have done this before and wrote in C or Objective-C,  hope you can help me out!

Really want and need to know how!

Thanks!

Comment: opening your file in PS gives this error : *Could not complete your request because a SOFn, DQT, or DHT JPEG marker is missing before a JPEG SOS marker.* Not sure how you got rid of that, but you'll have to save your image again.

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, I downloaded the image right from my ip cam. Seems I have to add it programmatically, that's real hassle and waste of time.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is an [Motion JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) file, not a JPEG image...

This does explain why browsers are able to open it and you can check this in vlc by looking at the codecs information :

> Motion JPEG Video (MJPG)

or even through `ffmpeg -i MeQ6p.jpg`:

> Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc

So your problem lies in your files only, and this can probably be fixed by setting your ip-cam to save still JPEG images instead of MJPEG streams.

Comment: I did found a way to wrap my 'image' as another jpeg file again and it woke fine, but this should be the real solution. thanks again!

Comment: By the way, can ffmpeg decode mjpeg stream frame by frame? Cause I need to fetch data over a tcp connection then combine data together not HTTP, so I can't just show it on a web view. Hope someone can tell me. In the meantime, I'm doing my research. Only want to solve this asap.

Comment: @gabrielchn, yes sure, you just have to do `ffmpeg -i MeQ6p.jpg outputframe%d.jpg` and it will extract all frames of your mjpeg to still jpeg files named `outputframe[n].jpg` (in given case there is only one frame)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and can see the data gets fetched from your posted URL and got some 17750 bytes.

```
let imageURL = NSURL(string : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeQ6p.jpg")
 let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURLFromParse! as NSURL)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! but if you write this line:       let img = UIImage(data: imgData!);          'img' will be nil.

Comment: Yep, seems something wrong with your image I tried with other image and everything works as expected. Please try by uploading a new image, doesn't seems to be a coding issue.

Comment: Every image has the same problem. I found a website can covert image to jpg, I simply upload and convert my image without other options, the image is repaired, maybe its about format issue.

Comment: May be its a format issue, but I tried with "jpg" only to check -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/R64uj.jpg in same code and able to get img from let img = UIImage(data: imgData!)  :)